# Kendo DataSource How to define a Model.Id when using DataTable

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

When defining a DataSource within @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model), I have successfully used

```
.DataSource( dataSource => .Ajax( ).Model( model => model.Id( m => m.PROPERTY ) ) )
```

where PROPERTY is a property of the object that is the model.  What is the correct syntax for defining Model.Id if the Model is a System.Data.DataTable and the Id column in the DataTable is TableId?

In other words, model.Id( m => ??? ).

I have tried, `model.Id( m => Model.PrimaryKey )`, which seems to satisfy the requirement that model.Id be set, but the Update Action (`.Update(update => update.Action("MyUpdateMethod", "MyController")`) doesn't ever hit, so I think there must still be something wrong.

Comment: I didn't even know you could bind it to a DataTable. If no one has an idea on how to do it, you may just need to define it in JavaScript instead of using an MVC helper.

Comment: @CodingWithSpike, could you point me to a sample?

Comment: In plain JavaScript you would set `new kendo.data.DataSource({ schema: { model: { id: "PrimaryKey" } } });` if you wanted to convert to JS instead of MVC helper, the easiest thing to do is use the MVC helper once, view the page in your browser, and copy/paste the generated JS code. Then replace your MVC helper razor code with the generated JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an answer, although it's not real slick.  There are several parts to it.

First, in order to Edit, I must set a Model.Id, how to do which was my original question.  The answer to that is simply, `model.Id( "KEY_COLUMN_NAME" )` in the .DataSource.Model method.  However, that is not enough to solve the problem that Update does not occur.  Telerik Support suggested that I needed to define a custom data object (POCO) that had all the same properties as the DataTable has columns.  That POCO becomes the type for the update

`public ActionResult MyUpdate( [DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest _request, MyPOCO _data ){...}`

The Editor can then map the DataRow columns to the POCO properties, and then MyUpdate can work.

Answer (score 2):

You can bind to a DataTable.  In fact, we do a lot of dynamic grids and DataTable is our only recourse.  Binding is a little different, though.

A snippet for one of ours is like this:

```
@model System.Data.DataTable
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .Name("SomeGrid")
    .Columns(columns=>
      { 
          foreach(System.Data.DataColumn column in Model.Columns)
          {
              columns.Bound(column.ColumnName).Title(column.Caption).Width(200);
          }
       }
    )
    .Selectable(selectable=>selectable
       .Type(GridSelectionType.Row)
    )
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Model(model =>
             {
                 foreach(System.Data.DataColumn column in Model.Columns)
                 { 
                     model.Field(column.ColumnName,column.DataType);
                 }
             }
         )
         .Read(read=>Action("SomeMethod", "SomeController"))
         .PageSize(20)
     )
```

Comment: Do you edit your data?  Although it is useful to show how a DataTable can be used in a grid, this was not the question.  The question was how to set the Model.Id.  I mentioned trouble getting Update to hit; I could have been clearer if I had said, without Model.Id, if you specify "Editable", you get "There is no DataSource Model Id property specified."

Comment: We do edit the data contained in the grid, but not inline.  We edit it in a popup kendo window.  But to do this, it has to be aware of the selection and we don't set it explicitly...it just magically happens.  You are trying to edit it inline?

Comment: When defining the Grid, we define .Editable( e => e.Mode(GridEditMode.Popup).TemplateName( "OurTemplate")...which gets us a popup editor.  Do you do it differently?  When we hit Submit, our controller action for update does not hit unless we defined a custom class (whose properties matched up with the DataColumns) as its 2nd parameter type (rather defeating the purpose, I know).  If I may ask, what does your Update method's signature look like?

Comment: I'm using Kendo UI (2013.2.918) and am also trying to bind a grid to a System.Data.DataTable. One problem I'm having is that my T-SQL statement returns columns with spaces in the column names. That does not violate a DataTable.. it's supported.. but I think it may not be supported by Kendo's Grid... I'm getting rowtemplate errors. Also, in the code snippet above - I don't see in my intellisense any prompt to define a .Model within .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource   .... )

Comment: I figured out that I have to create my own ClientRowTemplate to make DataColumns with ColumnNames containing spaces to work. Also, for my version of KendoUI, the DataSource->Model is now found under DataSource->Server->Model